# Best way to create user accounts from a file in Python?

Tags: python, file, file-upload, user-accounts

I am trying to have the ability to mass create user accounts from a file that I upload in Python. So instead of creating users one at a time I can be giving a list of X amount of users and quickly create them. So for instance if I have a file(newusers.csv) that contains the usernames below how would I go about easily doing this?

First name, Last name, Username.

tom        cat         tcat11

Jerry      Mouse       Jmouse21

Mini        Mouse       Mmouse

Below is the code I have which is supposed to create the users:

```
def user_account():
   userInformation = readFile("newusers.csv")
   try:
      subprocess.run(['useradd','-p', userInformation[1:]])
   except:
      print(f"failed to add user.")
      sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: How do you create a single user?

Comment: I am unsure, I cannot find much about adding any amount of users from a file. Is it just creating a user but uploading the file with the users before?

Comment: To where are you adding the users? is it in your own db or are you intending to e.g. send them to an API?

Comment: Can you upload the code which creates a user?

Comment: @Anamitra done!

Comment: It looks like you are adding a password for each user as well, where is the password coming from?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what specific options etc. you want in your `useradd` command so that i'm leaving out of this. However regarding the approach: This is one way you could approach it by creating a User class.

```py
import csv

class User:
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, username):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.username = username
    
    def save(self):
        try:
            # WHATEVER COMMAND AND OPTIONS YOU ARE LOOKING TO RUN
            # USING self.username, ETC. AS ARGS 
        except:
            print("failed to add user")
            sys.exit(1) # if you don't want to attempt any of the other users

    @staticmethod
    def mass_save(users):
        for user in users:
            user.save()

    @staticmethod
    def read_users_from_file(file_path):
        with open(file_path, "rt") as f:
            users = csv.reader(f)
            next(users) # Skip header row
            return [User(*row) for row in users] # Unpack each userinfo row from csv upon instantiation


if __name__ == "__main__":
    users = User.read_users_from_file("users.csv")
    User.mass_save(users)
```